# ZeroMQ publisher socket - raise event on subscription

Tags: zeromq, netmq

I was wondering if there is a way to raise events on new subscription to a publisher socket

For example:

```
        PublisherSocket publisher = new PublisherSocket();

        publisher.Bind("tcp://*:5555");

        NetMQPoller poller = new NetMQPoller { publisher };
        poller.RunAsync();

        poller.OnSubscription += topic =>
        {
            AddToPool(topic);
        };

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            SubscriberSocket sub = new SubscriberSocket();
            sub.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            sub.Subscribe("A");
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        publisher.ReceiveReady += Publisher_ReceiveReady;
```

Of course, **`OnSubscription`** doesn't really exist, but I was wondering if there is any way around it.

I need my server to be aware of all the subscriptions.

I though about two ways to implement it:

1. Create an additional router socket in the server, all subscriptions will be sent both to the publisher socket and to the router socket (unsubscriptions as well). This will allow me to poll the subscriptions from the router.
2. Not use publisher/subscriber at all, create all the pubsub mechanism with router/dealer.

What would you suggest me do?

Comment: As written in the zeroMQ guide it is not possible to track subscriptions, but having a look at [Advanced Pub-Sub-Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Reliable-Pub-Sub-Clone-Pattern) you will find a Reliable-Pub-Sub (Clone) Pattern, that is using a second ROUTER/DEALER socket to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an XPUB rather than PUB socket you can receive the subscription messages as you would regular messages on any other socket type.

Comment: It may be fair to note, that an **[An Answer]** and **[A Solution Proposal]** are two distinct things. **[An Answer] ought be "No, there is no such mechanism** in ZeroMQ transport-services for OnSubscription() functionalities, **but it is possible to add such behaviour** as an additional signalling, using a separate transport archetype or using the same but extended archetype `XPUB/XSUB` that provides means for code-based signalling of such an event and permits the opposite side to take action(s) like `raise` ..." That would be both true and fair.

Comment: @David Thank you for the reply, I've checked and it's indeed the case, i can listen to subscriptions, unsubscriptions via XPublisherSocket. It still won't be reliable enough for me. My plan is to make a server that raises subscription event whenever someone has started subscribing on some subscription and raises unsubscription event when no one is subscribed to that topic anymore. For that i'll have to keep track of all of the topics and clients identity and also implement an heartbeat mechanism to track disconnected clients.

Comment: @David i think that router socket is more suitable for the latter, since it knows all of the clients identities out of the box. Also, i wasn't able to implement heartbeat with XPublisher, it doesn't let me read messages that are unralated to subscriptions.